# System.InvalidOperationException executing Sqlite INSERT query in C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite

The following code tries to add a record to a table called `Contacts` in an Sqlite database.

```
public void addContactRecord(IContactRecord newContactRecord)
{
    using (var conn = new SqliteConnection(this.connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        
        var command = conn.CreateCommand();

        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Contacts (recordID, firstName, lastName, email) " + 
                             "VALUES (@recordID, @firstName, @lastName, @homeEmail);";
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = insertQuery;

        SqliteParameter idParam = new SqliteParameter();
        idParam.ParameterName = "@recordID";
        idParam.Value = "null";
        command.Parameters.Add(idParam);

        SqliteParameter firstNameParam = new SqliteParameter();
        firstNameParam.ParameterName = "@firstName";
        firstNameParam.Value = "'" + newContactRecord.firstName + "'";
        command.Parameters.Add(firstNameParam);

        SqliteParameter lastNameParam = new SqliteParameter();
        lastNameParam.ParameterName = "@lastName";
        lastNameParam.Value = "'" + newContactRecord.lastName + "'";
        command.Parameters.Add(lastNameParam);

        SqliteParameter homeEmailParam = new SqliteParameter();
        homeEmailParam.ParameterName = "@homeEmail";
        homeEmailParam.Value = "'" + newContactRecord.homeEmail + "'";
        command.Parameters.Add(homeEmailParam);  // exception is thrown here

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The `recordID` field in the database is AI and PK.

When trying to add the last SQL parameter, the following exception is thrown:
`System.InvalidOperationException: ParameterName must be set.`. The stack trace does not provide any further information beyond the line number at which the error is thrown. What is causing this?

Comment: In your insert query you named the last parameter "@email" while in the below lines of your code you actually give it as "@homeEmail". Did you already try to set the same name?

Comment: @rekcul I made a typo, it should be fixed now.

Comment: remove recordID  prarameter ... you are trying to set string "null" to integer column

Comment: @Selvin after removing that parameter (including from the sql query string), it still produces the same error.

Comment: You don't need to quote parameter values. That might not be your problem but I doubt that is what you want to end up in the database.

Comment: Are you sure that the line number in the exception is correct? Have you tried putting a break point on the line `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`? Does the debugger stop on the break point?